# Change frame of UIView and update the constraints of it childrens

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I need to change UI element based on what button was pressed, basically it is like a tab, but in just one part of my View Controller. The elements that I need to show/hide are UIView with multiple collection views and labels inside.

What I am doing right now Is defining both objects int he IB and programatically, when I need to show one I just set the width of one of them to 0 and set a new frame for the other one with the whole width I want. The problem with this approach is that even what the UIView is as I want it to be, the contents inside seem to keep the previous constraints (centered) and they don't "adapt" to the whole width.

Current Code:

```
var newFrame = self.view.frame
newFrame.origin.x = 0
newFrame.origin.y = self.blueView.frame.origin.y
newFrame.size.height = self.blueView.frame.size.height

if (showGreen){

    self.greenView.frame = newFrame
    self.greenView.hidden = false
    self.blueView.frame.size.width = 0.0
    self.blueView.hidden = true

}else{

    self.blueView.frame = newFrame
    self.blueView.hidden = false
    self.greenView.frame.size.width = 0.0
    self.greenView.hidden = true
}
```

In the IB I set the constraint for both views to have no separation between them and the margins.

I would like you to help me either in fixing this issue or with another way of achieving the desired behaviour behaviour.

Thank You.

[image: current situation and desired behaviour]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should change constraint.constant value, not the frame of UIView's,
make an IBOutlets for constraints you need, and change it this say:

```
self.widthConstraint.constant = newValue;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you. I used you answer to help me debug my problem, at the end I had some constraints that where getting int he way, so after solving that and using your suggestion everything works as I wanted.